Is it possible to recall the "Results" of a command that is run in bash?
I have a command that is running nx to handle ESLinting across some projects. I know I can use history to recall a specific command, however, while working on a fix, I am no longer seeing the original errors. Basically, they're fixed due to a caching issue, but the offending files still have the issues. Now when I run the same command, it only reviews the files I've changed (ie: ignores the previous failing ones)
for the sake of an example, previously running
nx run-many --all --target=lint

result:
 * nx run project1 [10 lint errors - filename]
 * nx run project2 [2 lint errors - filename]
 * nx run project3 [6 lint errors - filename]

But now, since the cache was fixed, I am seeing the following, despite not fixing these lint errors
nx run-many --all --target=lint

result:
 * nx run project1 [existing outputs match the cache, left as is]
 * nx run project2 [existing outputs match the cache, left as is]
 * nx run project3 [existing outputs match the cache, left as is]

Is there a way to recall that earlier command result?

... other than just scrolling up the terminal?

Unfortunately, it's fallen out of scroll range in the terminal - I've left the terminal open over the past few hours incase there was some type of history I didn't know of. But from searching, it sounds like I may be S.O.L.

Then if you hadn't taken some action beforehand, e.g., saving the output in a variable or a file, then, no, there's nothing to be done.

Unfortunate, but a lesson learned. Thank you!

There is apparently a --skipNxCache option , didn't that work?

@muru I had tried that, and also used cache=false, which shows it was run with an additional flag. I'm wondering now fit he original lint errors were a red herring. I will keep looking, thank you!

I suggest start using tmux. Along with all its features, it also brings a scroll buffer of about 2000 IIRC, and it's configurable anyways. With the ability to copy paste from the buffer to a file after the fact (with vim motions supported)

https://nx.dev/concepts/how-caching-works#what-is-cached  There may be a slight hope...
